# Нет перевода статьи в справке «I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Нет перевода статьи «I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?» в справке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question.

Comment: Видимо, это новая статья прилетела.

Comment: @alexolut в вебархиве по SOen первое упоминание от 15 Сентября. Видимо, вместе с адаптивным дизайном выкатили.

Comment: Большое спасибо за инициативу и перевод! Страница доступна для правки модераторам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Я переосмыслил свой вопрос; как его удалить?

Вы, вполне вероятно, можете переосмыслить свой вопрос. Возможно вы не хотите, чтобы ваши тиммейты видели конкретный вопрос о поиске работы, или вы осознали, что не должны были публиковать проприетарный код, или не хотите, чтобы ваши друзья видели ваш глупый вопрос. Если никто не ответ на ваш вопрос, **то можете** [**удалить его**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)**, никто вам не помешает**.

Однако, если на ваш вопрос даны хорошие ответы, было бы не честно удалять их вместе с вашим вопросом: другие участники потратили время и силы на помощь вам и, даже если вам не нужны больше эти ответы, они могут помочь другим участникам. Вот почему система не позволяет удалять отвеченные вопросы.

Но есть пара вещей, которые вы могли бы сделать:

- Если ваш вопрос слишком специфичный, отредактируйте его, чтоб сделать более абстрактным. Вам действительно нужны конкретные имена людей, вендоров? Ваше местоположение важно? Можете ли вы сделать код более общим и переименовать некоторые переменные?
- Если вы действительно не видите способов спасти свой вопрос путём удаления идентифицирующих деталей, и ни один из ответов не заплюсован, и, особенно, если вопрос был закрыт, вы можете использовать флаг, чтобы попросить модераторов удалить его.
- Если вы опубликовали какую-то чувствительную информацию (пароль, секретный ключ), отредактируйте вопрос и используйте флаг, чтобы попросить модераторов **убрать** их из истории правок. Будьте конкретны о том, чего именно хотите и почему. Такие запросы должны быть одобрены двумя модераторами, что подразумевает небольшую задержку. Если вопрос был закрыт, модератор может решить просто удалить вопрос. Почитайте [этот гайдлайн](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327145/1991579) о том, как лучше подготовить вопрос к правке, чтоб "не сломать" его или ответы.
- Если вопрос хороший, в нём нет чувствительной информации и проблема лишь в том, что там фигурирует ваше имя, вы можете [отсоединить его от своего аккаунта](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/260198). Это не настоящая анонимность; всё, что вы публикуете в Интернете, останется в нём навсегда. Запросы проходят ревью, что требует времени. Если ваш запрос одобрят, его нельзя будет отменить позже.

Несмотря на то, что редактирование истории правок и обезличивание возможны, не нужно ими злоупотреблять. Многократное использование подобных запросов может привести к временному бану аккаунта. Публикуйте с расчётом, что все ваши сообщения останутся публичными навечно.

Вандализм или чрезмерное удаление полезных сообщений может спровоцировать оповещение для команды модераторов. Пожалуйста, будьте уважительны в отношении других участников: избегайте аннулирования их работы и не мешайте им.

**Ничто из этого не может быть использовано для обхода блокировки системой** - если вам ограничена возможность публикации новых вопросов/ответов, пожалуйста, обратитесь к разделу [«Почему блокируются вопросы с моей учетной записи?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) и [«Почему блокируются ответы с моей учетной записи?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans).