# Рекурсивная ссылка в справке по удалению вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, справка, удаление-вопросов

На странице справки «[Я переосмыслил свой вопрос; как его удалить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)» есть ссылка на раздел по удалению вопроса:

> ... Если никто не ответ на ваш вопрос, **то можете [удалить его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question), никто вам не помешает.**

Сейчас ссылка ведет на ту же самую страницу хотя, судя по всему, должна вести на «[Почему и как удаляются некоторые вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)» (подсмотрел на аналогичной странице [en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)).

**Обновление:** Как пишет @Something в комментах, в справке к тому же есть опечатки:

> ... Если никто не *ответ* на ваш вопрос ...
>   Но *если* пара вещей, которые вы могли бы сделать:
>   Если вы *опубликовал* какую-то чувствительную информацию ...
>   должны быть одобрены двумя модераторами, что *подразумевают* небольшую задержку.

Текст можно еще утюжить и вообще обе страницы справки не очень конкретны, но это уже тема для отдельного обсуждения.

Comment: Кстати, там же опечатка (если никто не ответ на ваш вопрос).

Comment: @Something Спасибо! Там еще есть.

Comment: Сорри T_T https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8023/15479

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ссылку поменял.
2. Правки в текст внёс.

Если есть идеи/предложения, то лучше сразу вот в [этот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8186/15479) ответ вносить правки и пинговать меня в комментариях, чтоб я справку обновил.